# Repetitive tiling implies finite local complexity

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, tiling

My question probably needs to include the definitions of the terms in the title so I will first ask the question and then introduce the necessary definitions.

The following Theorem is stated without proof [here](http://tilings.math.uni-bielefeld.de/glossary/repetitive).

> Let $T$ be a tiling of the space $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $T$ is a
>   repetitive tiling, then $T$ has finite local complexity.

However, I think that there is a periodic (and so repetitive) tiling of the line $\mathbb{R}$ which does not have finitely many tile types, and so does not have finite local complexity, contradicting the statement. The example is given by the tiling $$T=\{t_{n,m}=[n+(1/2)^{m+1},n+(1/2)^{m}]\:|\:n\in\mathbb{Z},m=0,1\ldots\}.$$
$T$ is obviously a tiling of $\mathbb{R}$ as the union of all the $t_{n,m}$ cover the line, and the intersection of the interior of any two tiles is empty, and $T$ clearly has period 1 as $t_{n,m}+1=t_{n+1,m}$ and so is repetitive. Finally, $T$ has infinitely many tile types given by varying the value of $m$ for fixed $n$ and so $T$ does not have finite local complexity.

Have I missed something obvious in the definitions below, or my analysis of the above example, or is this really a counterexample to the stated Theorem? I think a clear fix would be if one restricted the definition of a tiling to those tilings, $T$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the intersection of any compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the tiles $t$ in $T$ is non-trivial for only finitely many $t$. In this case, it seems clear that the Theorem is true.

---

The necessary definitions are below.

**Tiling** [link](http://tilings.math.uni-bielefeld.de/glossary/tiling)

> We say the set $t\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a *tile* if $t$ is a
>   non-empty compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the closure of
>   the interior of $t$ is equal to $t$. We say a set of tiles
>   $T=\{t_{\lambda}|\lambda\in\Lambda\}$ is a *tiling* of $\mathbb{R}^n$
>   if
>
> - $\bigcup_{\Lambda} t_{\lambda}=\mathbb{R}^n$, and
> - for all $\lambda\neq \lambda'$, we have $\mbox{Int}(t_{\lambda})\cap \mbox{Int}(t_{\lambda'})=\emptyset$.

**Repetitive** [link](http://tilings.math.uni-bielefeld.de/glossary/repetitive)

> Let $T$ be a tiling of $\mathbb{R}^n$. We say $T$ is *repetitive* if, for all
>   $r>0$, $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, there exists a $\delta\in\mathbb{R}$ such
>   that, for any $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, there is some $z\in\mathbb{R}^n$
>   with $B_{r}[T,x]\sim B_{r}[T,z]$ and $|z-y|<\delta$.

Here, $B_{r}[T,x]=\{t\in T\:|\:t\cap B_r(x)\neq\emptyset\}$ is the set of tiles in $T$ which have non-trivial intersection with the open ball $B_r(x)$ of radius $r$ and centre $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. We say two sets of tiles are $\sim$-equivalent if a translation of $\mathbb{R}^n$ exists which takes one set to another.

**Finite local complexity** [link](http://tilings.math.uni-bielefeld.de/glossary/flc)

> We say that $T$ has *finite local complexity* if, for all $r>0$ the
>   set $\{B_r[T,x]\:|\:x\in\mathbb{R}^n\}/{\sim}$ is finite.

Note that if $T$ does not have finitely many tile types, then $T$ does not have FLC. By tile types, we mean the $\sim$-equivalence classes of single tiles in $T$.

Comment: With these definitions, there are no repetitive tilings: Let $x\in\mathbb R^n$ and $r>0$ be arbitrary, let $t$ be a tile with $x\in t$. As $t$ is compact, it has finite diameter and $t\cap B_r(z)=\emptyset$ if $|z-x|>\operatorname{diam}(t)+r$. No matter what $\delta>0$ we choose, we can find $y$ with $|y-x|>\operatorname{diam}(t)+r+\delta$ and then $t\in B_r[T,x]$ and $t\notin B_r[T,z]$ for all $z$ with $|z-y|<\delta$. Your definition does not even resemble what you link to.

Comment: I think that you mean $B_r[T,x]\sim B_r[T,z]$ in your definition of *repetitive*.

Comment: I do, thanks for the spot.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like one needs some extra condition, such as local finteness (i.e. each point has an open neighbourhood that intersects only finitely many tiles)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the author of the page you refer to. Yes, you are right: One needs to require locally finite. I will change the text on the page you mention. In carefully written papers or books this theorem is stated as follows: "Let $\Lambda \subset \mathbb R^d$ be a locally finite point set that is repetitive. Then, $\Lambda$ is also FLC." (see Baake, Grimm: "Aperiodic Order" Cambridge University Press 2013, Proposition 5.5, p. 140, where you find also a proof)

Comment: Many thanks for the response and reference. On a personal note, I would also like to thank you for contributing to the wonderful resource that is the tilings encyclopedia. It's been invaluable in my studies so far.